# How to open new video in locked screen

Tags: java, android

I have a video watch app. I want to watch video in locked screen, and it is working. but some Api version i can watch but can't change video, can't open in rotated screen in some Api version. My code is belove

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
    WindowManager wm= (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display dp= wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    if (dp.getHeight()<dp.getWidth())
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        else {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch_landscape);
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch);}

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When ı delete this code line, problem solved

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
```